# cron management

Tags: server

I have crontabs across multiple servers using different accounts.  The scripts are separated such for a reason, different users for different services, etc.  I did some searching for a tool to track what is running where in a central location, but didn't find anything.  How are others keeping track of their crontabs?  I'm writing some code now to fetch the crontabs from the servers and aggregate them in a central place, but was wondering if anyone has an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: This would be a better match for Server Fault I think

Comment: Agree.  While there are many things like this which fall into our duties, they're unfortunately outside of the mandate of the site.

Comment: Ah, cool... didn't know about Server Fault... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've placed crontabs in `/etc/cron.d`, given them a unique name (usually the hostname of the server) and checked those files into a central version control repository.

Comment: I like the VCS approach... I'll definitely include that in whatever I end up doing.  Thanks.